# React Native url response in app browser cannot find as null

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

Im trying to extract a url from an in-app browser and I am having some trouble any ideas are welcome!

The link will open successfully but when I click the cancel button on the in-app browser the link returns as null.

```
      try {
        const isAvailable = await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()
        
        if (isAvailable) {
          InAppBrowser.open(url, {
            // iOS Properties
            dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
            preferredBarTintColor: 'gray',
            preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
            // Android Properties
            showTitle: true,
            toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
            secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
            enableUrlBarHiding: true,
            enableDefaultShare: true,
            forceCloseOnRedirection: true,
          }).then((response) => {

            console.log("JSON REsponse:",JSON.stringify(response))
         
            console.log("JSON REsponse:",JSON.stringify(response))
            
            Linking.getInitialURL().then(initialUrl => {
            console.log("test:",initialUrl as string);
             });
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try By removing JSON.stringify in console.log only print response

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately this does not work :( have you other ideas?